How can I create an applicationSet using Argocd API
Creation of a applicationSet using argocd API

I am trying to create an applicationSet using argocd API. I followed the argocd API swagger documentation where I provided the JSON object where I defined the metadata of the application set and using Postman I am testing this endpoint:

https://localhost:8081/api/v1/applicationsets

I added the bearer token in the Authorization and the context-type : application/json in the header and in the body I added the JSON.
This is my full JSON object:
   { 
  "metadata": {
    "name": "applicationset-v6",
    "namespace": "argocd"
  },
  "spec": {
    "goTemplate": true,
    "goTemplateOptions": [
      "missingkey=error"
    ],
    "generators": [
      {
        "list": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "name": "feature-ijk",
              "branch": "branch-ijk",
              "expireDate": "2024-12-31",
              "namespace": "test-namespace"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "feature-ijk"
      },
      "spec": {
        "project": "default",
        "source": {
          "repoURL": "https://github.com/org/project-test.git",
          "targetRevision": "main",
          "path": "main/helm",
          "helm": {
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "global.namespace.endDate",
                "value": "2024-12-31"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "destination": {
          "server": "https://kubernetes.default.svc",
          "namespace": "test-namespace"
        },
        "syncPolicy": {
          "automated": {
            "prune": true,
            "selfHeal": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


and this is the error I got (500 Internal Server Error):
{
    "error": "error creating ApplicationSets: ApplicationSets is nil in request",
    "code": 2,
    "message": "error creating ApplicationSets: ApplicationSets is nil in request"
}

Any Suggestion please?

Please post text information as text, not as images

Thank you @RohitGupta , i added text info i hope is much better now ?
